# Python method parameter restricted class

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, methods, restriction

I want to restrict a parameter within a set of options. If the function is called a parameter must be restricted to a couple of options.
This is what I have until now

```
class GetFileMethod:
     URL = 'url'
     ATTACHMENT = 'attachment'

class MailClient
     def GetFile(self,method)

MailClient.GetFile(GetFileMethod.URL) #works ok, but
MailClient.GetFile("lalala") #should raise an error
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def GetFile(self, method):
    if  method not in {'url','attachment'}:
        raise ValueError
```

I would   make `GetFileMethod` a method of the `MailClient` class and it will make life easier controlling the input.

Comment: For sensible and unambiguous phrasing, Python also allows `method not in collection`.

Comment: @YannVernier, yes, changed, did not even realise I wrote it that way

Answer (score 0):

Change your `class MainClient` to this:- 
you need to check the value of `method` that you are providing in the namespace of the `class GetFileMethod` so that :-

```
GetFileMethod.__dict__.values()


class MailClient:
    def GetFile(self, method):
        if method in GetFileMethod.__dict__.values():
            return 'Yes'
        else:
            return 'No'
```

Comment: try `MailClient().GetFile(None)`